# Run Python script through Excel VBA

Tags: python, excel, vba, connection

I have trouble running a python script from Excel VBA. This is the VBA code:

```vb
Sub RunPython()
    
    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim PythonExe, PythonScript As String
    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    PythonExe = """C:\Users\carlo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.exe""" 
    PythonScript = """C:\Users\carlo\Desktop\MSc_Thesis\ML applications\BlackBox\BlackBoxAbsorbers.py"""  
    objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript

End Sub
```

The python code is the following.

```py
print("hello")
input("hello, press enter")
```

When I run VBA, the python executer opens but it immediately closes without actually executing the script. In other words, neither `"hello"` nor `"hello, press enter"` appear on the python executer window, which suddenly closes.

I'm sure the paths to the python.exe and to the python script are correct. I've tried them both with `""""` and with `""` and in both cases it does not work. Obviously (it's super simple!) the python script works if I run it directly from the python executer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need a space between `PythonExe & " " & PythonScript`. So the command you run is `"C:\…\python3.exe" "C:\…\BlackBoxAbsorbers.py"` with space between the program path and the python script.

Also note that `Dim PythonExe, PythonScript As String` only declares `PythonScript As String` but `PythonExe As Variant`. In VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable: `Dim PythonExe As String, PythonScript As String` or it is `Variant` by default!

Further `objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript` is not properly debugable. I recommend to put the command into a variable so you are able to print it in the immediate window for debugging:

```vb
Dim Command As String
Command = PythonExe & PythonScript

Debug.Print Command

objShell.Run Command
```

If you do this you will see that the output of your command is:

```
"C:\Users\carlo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.exe""C:\Users\carlo\Desktop\MSc_Thesis\ML applications\BlackBox\BlackBoxAbsorbers.py"
```

And there is no space between the 2 strings, where it actually should be:

```
"C:\Users\carlo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.exe" "C:\Users\carlo\Desktop\MSc_Thesis\ML applications\BlackBox\BlackBoxAbsorbers.py"
```

So I recommend:

```
Public Sub RunPython()    
    Dim objShell As Object
    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

    Dim PythonExe As String
    PythonExe = """C:\Users\carlo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.exe""" 

    Dim PythonScript As String
    PythonScript = """C:\Users\carlo\Desktop\MSc_Thesis\ML applications\BlackBox\BlackBoxAbsorbers.py"""  

    Dim Command As String
    Command = PythonExe & " " & PythonScript

    objShell.Run Command
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for answering me! But unfortunately, even your version of the code does not work for me.. :((

Comment: @CarloCortellini does `Shell Command` work?

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED!! I can't understand why, but splitting objShell.Run PythonExe and objShell.Run PythonScript it works fine! Like that:

```
Public Sub RunPython()    
    Dim objShell As Object
    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

    Dim PythonExe As String
    PythonExe = """C:\Users\carlo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.exe""" 

    Dim PythonScript As String
    PythonScript = """C:\Users\carlo\Desktop\MSc_Thesis\ML applications\BlackBox\BlackBoxAbsorbers.py"""  
    
     objShell.Run PythonExe
     objShell.Run PythonScript

End Sub
```

Thanks anyway @Pᴇʜ , I'll rate your answer as positive 'cause you have been very kind!!

Comment: Just check if it works without `objShell.Run PythonExe`. And of course you can accept your own answer as solution (after 1 day I think).

Comment: Then that means it works because windows linked the `.py` file type with the python automatically.